# Simple plugins to post info about new blog entries?

Tags: facebook, notifications, google-plus

I am looking for some plugins that would automatically post information about new blog entries (posts) to my facebook/google+ pages.

But - simple search through plugins listing shows that such plugins don't exists, or are rare. Most of the plugins offer content sharing the other way (i.e. display entries from facebook/google+ in your wordpress blog), or simply provide  a way to have "Like"/"+1" buttons.

Can anyone of you suggest a simple plugin to send notifications about new blog posts?

Comment: Best really is to use a site like hootsuite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Facebook:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

For Twitter:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/

For Google+
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-google-connect/

The twitter and facebook plugins will autopost from your site to each service. The G+ plugin is new, and still under development. I don't know that there is any plugin yet that pushes notifications to G+....

Comment: Despite their names, they clearly are not simple, and (at least FB one) provides *way* more functionality. As for the G+ - it doesn't seem to be able to create posts on G+ when I will publish new post in wordpress - so it doesn't do what I need.

Comment: That's what I was saying at the end of my post, I don't believe ANY plugins currently do that. I'm not sure that feature works with G+ yet. If it did, it would be in that plugin.

Comment: There isn't a way to post directly to G+ yet because Google hasn't opened the API. So if you're waiting for a plugin built to do that specifically, you might be waiting a long time.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. I pretty much rest easy with SGC knowing that if a desireable feature is opened up by G+, Otto will include it.

Comment: All three plugins don't seem to exist anymore ("We couldn't find that plugin. Maybe you were looking for one of these?") ... are there good alternatives?